# Updating Automation Object via Fuel SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, php, fuel-sdk

I'm having trouble getting an Automation to update via the Fuel SDK (PHP flavor). I can retrieve the object's properties, but cannot seem to update. My code:

```
$objectType = 'Automation';
$properties = [
  'CustomerKey' => '9364d8cc-0fdf-de12-b284-e3a770ca91b8',
  'Description' => 'Lorem ipsum'
];

$patchAutomationsResponse = new ET_Patch($etClient, $objectType, $properties);
```

I've also tried using `ObjectID` and `ProgramID` to no avail.

The system returns a 200 status Okay with a StatusMessage of "Program updated," but nothing updates.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of PHP Fuel SDK are you on? 0.9?

Comment: @GauravKheterpal Yes, 0.9.

Comment: Interesting. I would recommend raising it as a bug here if you can consistently reproduce it - https://github.com/ExactTarget/FuelSDK-PHP/issues

Comment: Does the status of the automation show it's running?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews I'm not sure. The value for status returned is `7`

Comment: [IsActive] => 1
    [Status] => 7